# Python MLLib KMeans algorithm - maxIterations definition

Tags: python, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using `MLlib` for the first time with Python and I'm struggling with a simple task: I need to define a number of `maxIterations` for a `KMean` algorithm. Whereas in Scala it works well:

```
val kmeans = new KMeans
kmeans.setK(K)
kmeans.setMaxIterations(maxNumIters)
```

The same approach for Python doesn't:

```
kmeans = KMeans().setK(K).setMaxIterations(maxNumIters)
```

And I got the error:

> AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'setMaxIterations'

I couldn't find in the documentation (possibly my fault), but basically, my question is: **How do I define, (in Python), the `MaxIterations` for a `KMeans` algorithm?**

Comment: I think you should use in KMeans the "maxIterations" parameter instead of "setMaxIterations". https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/clustering.html#KMeans.train

Comment: Thanks, @n1tk definitely it is a possible approach - during the train. I was looking for a possibility to instantiate with the values though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a way:

```
kmeans = KMeans().setK(K).setMaxIter(maxNumIters)
```

By the way, paying more attention to detail, I could find some useful information in the command below that allowed me to see it wasn't `setMaxIterations` but instead `setMaxIter`:

```
kmeans = KMeans()
print(kmeans.explainParams())
```

Explanation:

```
featuresCol: features column name. (default: features)
initMode: The initialization algorithm. This can be either "random" to choose random points as initial cluster centers, or "k-means||" to use a parallel variant of k-means++ (default: k-means||)
initSteps: The number of steps for k-means|| initialization mode. Must be > 0. (default: 2)
k: The number of clusters to create. Must be > 1. (default: 2)
maxIter: max number of iterations (>= 0). (default: 20)
predictionCol: prediction column name. (default: prediction)
seed: random seed. (default: -7649703878154674547)
tol: the convergence tolerance for iterative algorithms (>= 0). (default: 0.0001)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your kmeans model using:-

```
model = KMeans.train(sc.parallelize(data), maxIterations=10)
```

where data is your training data. for more parameters see [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/clustering.html#KMeans.train).